# Local account to local node

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, accounts

If I create my wallet / accounts client-side with web3.eth.accounts how can I "publish" them on my local node?

For example, I want to send some ether with an eth faucet to the first created account.

I'm using geth 1.6.7. In theory I can send few ether without pay for the gas, but I can't. [1.6.7 release](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.6.7)

Answer (score 1):

Before it gets a balance or sends transactions, an account consists purely of a number, made from another number: An address, made by deriving a public key from a private key, which is a random number. It doesn't need an entry on the blockchain.

Once you've created the address on your local node, you can simply enter the address into the faucet and send ETH to it. No further publishing step is required.

Comment: How long It takes? I created a new account and send 3eth from faucet, but I can't see them on etherscan.

Comment: Presumably this is a testnet - are you sure you're looking at the right testnet on etherscan? Normally the ropsten faucet seems to get payments through within a minute or so.

Comment: I start geth with --testnet flag. And I use this service http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/

Comment: Are you looking here for your 3 ETH? https://ropsten.etherscan.io/
Your geth flags should have nothing to do with whether you can see ETH from the faucet on the block explorer, the addresses are the same for any network.

Comment: Yes I'm looking here https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x066DE90608891EB9Bf8F2f73C5a22131c95C4960 but no eth was send

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `--testnet` flag in GETH.  Since there are several testnets you would need to specify the testnet name or chainId.  Try starting geth with the `--ropsten` flag and resend the eth from the faucet to one of the newly generated accounts and it should work™.